# Issues with duplicating TFS 2005 to a virtual server

Tags: tfs

We have a problem with our current TFS installation. For some reason, which I won't get into, the Sharepoint DBs (sts_content, sts_config) got corrupted. So now, none of our team-project sites work, we have no access to our documents and can't create new team projects. We can still work with the version control, though.

We wanted to "play" with the server and try to fix it, without affecting the users. So we duplicated the server to a virtual one. We now continued and changed all of the relevant configuration to point to the new server, as explained in the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx).

The step of rebuilding the warehouse (with setupwarehouse) failed. Also, we can't access the VersionControl web service (ourserver:8080/VersionControl/v1.0/repository.asmx). We are seeing errors in the EventLog:

TF53002: Unable to obtain registration data for application Build.
TF53005: Unable to retrieve the Team Foundation Server installed UI culture.
TF53002: Unable to obtain registration data for application VersionControl.
TF30040: The database is not correctly configured. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.

The solutions suggested in [this blog post](http://team-foundation-server.blogspot.com/2009/03/tfs-2008-sp1-upgrade-nightmare.html) did not assist. So now we're kind of stuck.
Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Might be worth posting this across at Server Fault, for a better response.
Bob.

Comment: Done that, but not response there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really old question, but what I would suggest doing is installing a fresh copy of Team Foundation Server 2010, then in the configuration wizard, select 'Upgrade' and choose your existing TFS2005 databases. This will allow you to get a working server up and running, without SharePoint and the Cube/Warehouse configured. You can then tackle each of those problems separately via the TFS Administration Console.